# does amazon corretto jdk supports BIRT report?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, birt

we were using Oracle JDK for BIRT report and now we are using amazon corretto jdk.

Below error is raising while running the BIRT reports.
org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine

Can you please confirm does amazon corretto jdk supports BIRT report?
if so, which carretto vesrion supports BIRT 4.9?

Thanks,
Suma

Comment: Same versions of JDKs from Oracle and of Amazon Corretto behave same. They do not differ technically (both are HotSpot VMs) but in terms of the license.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT 4.9 needs Java 11 - it does not require an *Oracle* JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. that means we can use amazon corretto JDK's for BIRT.  Any idea when the "Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine" trigger?